# No search results in Kibana when searching for a specific keyword

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, log4net

I installed ELK stack on my windows 10 machine. I used log4net to push logs to logstash -> elasticsearch. The logs data is displayed in Kibana and everything is fine. My logstach config is:

```
input {
udp {
port => 5960
codec => multiline {
        charset => "UTF-8"
        pattern => "^(DEBUG|WARN|ERROR|INFO|FATAL)"
        negate => true
        what => previous
    }
type => "log4net"
}
}
output {
elasticsearch {
hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
index => "myindex"
}
}
```

When I try to search for a keyword that exists in the message text (using the search input and the date is set to 3 months ago) I get:

```
"No results match your search criteria"
```

**Note**: If I use: stdin {} instead of udp{} in logstash config I can search for any keyword.

I reinstalled the stack in another machine and the same issue happened.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

The problem was with the encoding data coming from log4net. So you need to set the log4net config file as following for udp appender:

```
<appender name="UdpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.UdpAppender">
<remoteAddress value="127.0.0.1" />
<remotePort value="5960" />
<encoding value="UTF-8" />
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout, log4net">
  <conversionPattern value="%-5level %date [%-5.5thread] %-40.40logger - %message%newline" />
</layout>
```